# Confidence Interval for LightGBM Regressor

Tags: regression, lightgbm

Is there a way to get confident score / percentage error when predicting? . I used light GBM Regressor(in python 3.6) to train my data .
In addition to the prediction I want to have an estimate of the error .

Answer (score 2):

In LightGBM, try using Quantile regression instead of the basic regression we use. Set 'objective' parameter as 'quantile'. You may have to set other parameters as well. Check the API [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html)